# How do I get my modal to slide in horizontally from the left?

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, bootstrap-modal

When I feed in

```
 Modal.show("experimentMakeAnOffer");
```

in the Chrome browser **console**, my modal slides in diagonally from the left. How do I get my modal to slide in horizontally (in a straight line) from the left instead?

I have tried researching on how to level the modal (while hidden/before being called) using CSS, but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

**Below my modal in template:**

```
 <template name="experimentMakeAnOffer">
    <div class="modal fade left" id= "experimentMakeAnOffer2">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <h4 class="modal-title">experimentMakeAnOffer  </h4>                </div>
            <div class="modal-body experimentMakeAnOffer">           
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitOffer btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Offer</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.modal.fade:not(.in).left .modal-dialog {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: What is the css for the modal-dialog (without the .fade)? The reason I ask is because translate3d(-25%, -20%, 0) means its sliding the modal 25% right, 20% down so its already starting in the top left of the page.

Comment: @Pat Sorry Pat that was a typo that has been corrected. The way it is in my CSS code is: 

    .modal.fade:not(.in).left .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
    } But it still slides in diagonally.

Answer (score 3):

Hello check the below  updated Fiddle where I changed your code and showed it another way Hope it helps You .

```
.modal.left .modal-dialog
{
position: fixed;
margin: auto;
width: 500px;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left .modal-content
{   
margin-top:40%;
height: 50%;
width:100%;
overflow-y: auto;
}   
.modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
left: -320px;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
left: 0;
}
```

[Left side Modal Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/mu5mvba0/507/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is how it originally is in my CSS file `.modal.fade:not(.in).left .modal-dialog {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
}`(sorry corrected my original question). But the modal still slides in diagonally.

Comment: didn't it come from the left side which you wanted did you check the fiddle or you want another type ?

Comment: will you please check the  updated fiddle ??I change a bit of your code

Answer (score 2):

The `translate3d` property accepts (X, Y, Z, angle)  property.

On your CSS the statement is inconsistent, because first you set the Y for 20% on `-webkit-transform` and then you set it to 0% on `transform`, the browser will only get the last valid argument, so for instance on Chrome the `.model-dialog` will be rendered 0 on Y.

But regarding your question to show from the left you need to change the X position and not the Y position of your translate.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgvuzqkj/) for an quick demo

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Lucas, however the original question posting had a typo in the CSS part.  X values in Both `-webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);` and 
`transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);` are both 25%. The question has since been corrected.

Comment: @SirBT Oh! I see, are you still experiencing the issue? I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Yes sadly still experiencing the same issue